# Cannot use case when statement in JPA @Query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a Spring Boot application that has the friendship functionality. I have User, Friendship entities and FriendshipDTO(for simplicity I removed JPA annotations):

```
public class User {
 private Long id;
 private String email;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String phone;
 private String login;
 ....
}

public class Friendship {
 private Long id;
 @ManyToOne
 private User fromUser;
 @ManyToOne
 private User toUser;
 private FriendStatus friendStatus;
 private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}

public class FriendshipDTO {
 private Long id;
 private User friend;
}
```

I want to get all friendships by user id and map it to FriendshipDTO:

```
    @Query("select new com.dto.FriendshipDTO(fr.id, "
        + "case when fr.fromUser.id = :id then fr.toUser "
        + "else fr.fromUser end) "
        + "from Friendship fr " +
        + "join fr.fromUser "
        + "join fr.toUser "
        + "where fr.friendStatus = 'ACCEPTED' "
        + "and (fr.toUser.id = :id or fr.fromUser.id = :id)")
Page<FriendshipDTO> findAllFriendshipsByUserId(@Param("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

It seems JPA doesn't like **case when then** in the select operation and as the result throws an exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedMapping (org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedMapping are in unnamed module of loader 'app')] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedMapping (org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedMapping are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Without **case when then** works fine.

```
    @Query("select new com.campuslink.campuslinkbackend.dto.FriendshipDTO(fr.id, "
        + "fr.toUser ) "
        + "from Friendship fr " +
        + "join fr.fromUser "
        + "join fr.toUser "
        + "where fr.friendStatus = 'ACCEPTED' "
        + "and (fr.toUser.id = :id or fr.fromUser.id = :id)")
Page<FriendshipDTO> findAllFriendshipsByStudentId(@Param("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why It doesn't work?

Comment: Can we see application properties ?

Comment: You'll want to check the JPA specification, but CASE only supports scalar_expressions, so it does not support entity/path expressions.